# Merging Magento and Dreamweaver, Xampp

Tags: php, magento

Im a beginner for Magento, I need to know what are the requirements and how to bring those into my computer. Also I tried to install Magento from www.Magentocommerce.com, also Installed Dreamweaver for PHP coding, Xampp server. Im not sure how to merge all these to know, how Magento works.

Following is my system config:
Windows 7 Ultimate, 64bit, Intel Pentium processor, 2GB RAM.

Can someone help me to install all the above for Magento and assist me regularly, whenever I struggle to solve my need?

Comment: magento is a CMS of php, Dreamweaver is used to program php, and Xampp is used as php server.. So all three are different.. Merging these all is not possible.. First learn basics of php and than go for magento...

Comment: Thank you for your respond, Nishant. I will learn it..

Answer (score 0):

Nishant was right.

Magento is a openSource E-Commerce System.
XAMPP is an X-Os Apache MySQL PHP environment.
Dreamweaver is a tool used to do programming stuff.

I guess You ask about how to code in magento using dreamweaver and deploy it to dreamweaver.

Steps:
I guess apache and dreamweaver has been installed and it is ready to install magento now.

1. Install Magento - Copy the downloaded and extracted(unzipped) magento folder to your XAMPP/htdocs directory.
2. Start the apache and MySQL server using the XAMPP services control panel if it is not started already.
3. Access the magento folder in your browser using the following url http://localhost/yourmagentofolder/
4. Follow the steps. Magento will be installed.
5. After Installation Start Dreamweaver and select Site > New Site. The Site Setup dialog box appears.
6. In the Site Name text box, enter "YourSiteName" as the name of the site. The name is used internally by Dreamweaver to identify the site. It doesn't matter if it contains spaces.
7. Click the folder icon next to the Local Site Folder text box to browse to and select the bayside_beat folder.The Site Setup dialog box should now look like
   [image]
8. Click Save. That's it!
9. You can also explore the site manager in dreamweaver so that it will be useful.

You can refer this URL for Magento how it works. http://www.techflirt.com/tutorials/magento-tutorial/magento-directory-structure-files.html

Sources: [Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/how-to/first-website-part1.html)